Quickly bring one line of spaghetti chart into focus in Excel
I have a spaghetti chart similar to this one:

I would like to take one line and make it "stand out", making the others less visible. Is there anyway I can do this quickly and easily (i.e., without going into Format Data Series for each individual line)?

Would the downvoter care to explain his or her reasoning?

My preferred answer would be "don't do this kind of chart", it's ugly. However, if you must, you probably do have to format each line, or make a VBA macro to do that. You could also just make the one line thicker, but that makes it even more crowded

@InHocSigno People downvote on Stack Exchange sites for the most bizarre reasons (give a small person a small amount of power...).  My recommendation: Just ignore it.  I upvoted your question because it's a quality question and I'm interested in the answer too.  I also added the 'charts' tag for you.

tl;dr
I've done many charts similar to this.  Is there any way to do this quickly and easily? As with most Excel items-sort of.  The big question for you is what message are you trying to convey.  The answer will point you in the best direction.
Starting with this mess:

1. Quick 6 Color Application Using Themes
Excel uses the Color Theme to auto-magically color your series.  You can quickly recolor your series by modifying your color theme.  Access it from Page Layout > Themes > Colors.  Excel uses the Text/Background-Dark 1 color for font color, axis labels, horizontal grid lines, chart title, and legend title.  After that, the series are colored, in order, by Accents 1-6.  If you have more than 6 series, they are colored by a darker variation of 1-6 (this seems to repeat in the pattern of 6 accents darker followed by 6 accents lighter).
So, if you want your first series highlighted and the rest of the series subdued, you can create a custom color theme with Accent 1 a highlighted color and the remaining Accents 2-6 all a mid-gray.

For series beyond the first 6, you'll need to manually format each of those, although they'll all start from the same base color.  If you manipulate your data, you could capitalize on the repetitive nature and only populate the series "slots" that are of the color you want and fill the remainder in with NULLs, although that's probably more work than just formatting the series.

2. VBA
If you have a set pattern that you want to follow, and your environment allows for Macros, you could use VBA to color your charts however you like.  Using the script below, a single macro transforms the original to this:

Sub format_chart_series()

Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim p As Integer
Dim pcnt As Integer
Dim gray As String
Dim red As String
Dim ltgreen As String
Dim white As String

If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then ' Error trap to ensure a chart is selected
    MsgBox "Please: Select a chart and try again.", vbExclamation
Else

n = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count ' Set n to the number of series in chart
p = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Points.Count ' Set p to the number of points in series

' Set chart colors
gray = RGB(192, 192, 192)
red = RGB(192, 0, 0)
ltgreen = RGB(155, 187, 89)
white = RGB(255, 255, 255)

' Format Background Series
For i = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.Weight = 0.5
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = gray
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.Transparency = 0.5
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).ApplyDataLabels ShowSeriesName:=0, ShowValue:=0
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).MarkerStyle = 0
Next i

' Format Index Series
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.Weight = 1 ' Sets line weight
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = red ' Sets line color as red
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.BackColor.RGB = white

' Formats Index Series Points
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).MarkerStyle = 2 ' Sets marker as diamond
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).MarkerSize = 6 ' Sets marker size
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).MarkerBackgroundColor = red
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).MarkerForegroundColor = white

' Labels Index Series Points
For pcnt = 1 To p
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(pcnt).ApplyDataLabels ShowValue:=1
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(pcnt).DataLabel.Font.Color = red
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(pcnt).DataLabel.Font.Size = 8
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(pcnt).DataLabel.Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
Next pcnt

' Labels Index Series End Point
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(p).ApplyDataLabels ShowSeriesName:=1, ShowValue:=1, ShowCategoryName:=0 ' Adds label series name
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(p).DataLabel.Separator = vbCr
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(p).DataLabel.Font.Color = red  ' Sets label as red
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(p).DataLabel.Font.Size = 8
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(p).DataLabel.Font.Bold = 1  ' Sets label as bold
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(p).DataLabel.Position = xlLabelPositionRight  ' Sets label position to right

' Format Median Series
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.Weight = 4
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = ltgreen
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.Transparency = 0.5

' Reorder Index Series to top
' ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).PlotOrder = n

End If ' Error trap chart select

End Sub

Finally, in similar situations, I often format all of my rows as the background series type above (mid-gray), then use a dynamic range to create a highlighted series that can be selected from a drop-down to isolate the data of interest.  Also, when using historical data, I'll often highlight the current (or focal time period), and then progressively lighten the series as they represent older data so that the pattern is visible, but the visual impact lightens the further back the data represents.  So, in this chart Red highlights the current year-to-date, Dark Gray represents last year, and the other grays represent prior years 2-9.

